# it is possible to change the width and height of an swf with AS3 onclick event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

> it is possible to change the width and height of an swf with AS3 onclick event ?

see image : [change the width and height of an swf with AS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf8KV.jpg)

[image]

Comment: One sentence is not enough info to help you... Is this when swf is embeded in a web page? Something like this **[demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/flash_resize_via_js.html)**?... Or you mean you want your content inside a MovieClip and then scale the MC object on click? Remember MovieClips have own timeline (frames etc) so they can be used like an alternative container to Stage. Why would you want to change the entire Stage size? Explain your goal and maybe advice can be given...

Comment: thank you for reacting to my first question ,

Comment: my goal is when i open the swf , a will have a possibility to resize the entire animation window by clicking a button .....swf is not embedded in a web page , and also i don't know if there is a possibility to make the swf window appear transparent  (this is an other quest :) ...)

Comment: the animation will be without menu bar and borders it like in ( macromedia director as i remember ) or it like  the **** first screen ****  when we open an adobe product

i hope you understand what i mean  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not if you are targeting FlashPlayer. From your comments it looks like you want to build a standalone application.

Target the Adobe Air runtime for that. It is meant to b a standalone application that's not embedded in a website. It provides access to additional features, such as`NativeWindow`.